# compile error with function pointer declaration

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, openssl

I'm trying to import openssl to my swift project, but when I add `#import "ras.h"` in the `xxx-Bridging-Header.h`, I got the compile error below.

```
<unknown>:0: error: /Users/wenyun/workspace/newsvn/newios/ios/VanJoyPay2/VanJoyPay2/opensource/OpenSSLRSAWrapper/openssl/include/openssl/rsa.h:100: expected ')'
<unknown>:0: note: /Users/wenyun/workspace/newsvn/newios/ios/VanJoyPay2/VanJoyPay2/opensource/OpenSSLRSAWrapper/o penssl/include/openssl/rsa.h:100: to match this '('
```

The ras.h:100 is:

```
int (*rsa_mod_exp)(BIGNUM *r0,const BIGNUM *I,RSA *rsa,BN_CTX *ctx); /* Can be null */
```

I fixed the error by renaming the `const BIGNUM *I` to `const BIGNUM *i`.  Does anybody know why the character `I` is so special?

I did another test today, the result looks so odd.
I created a new swift project, wrote  3 header files:

```
test.h
int test(char *I);

test2.h
#import "test3.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

test3.h
int test3();


xxx-Bridging-Header.h
#import "test2.h"
#import "test.h"
```

I got the compile error again!

finally,  removing "#import " makes everything ok.

> `Why the character "I" could not work together with #import <xxx>?`

Comment: This looks odd (notice the extra space in between the letters of OpenSSL): `.../OpenSSLRSAWrapper/o penssl/include/...`.

Comment: this looks like someone `#define I` somewhere, you can check the result from preprocessor to see what happened

Comment: We can use `#undef I` to remove the definition.

Comment: I WANT to get `I` and the complex functions, how did you import them??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not tied to Swift. It is caused by a previous definition of `I` in the `/usr/include/complex.h` file (as [Brian Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642626/bryan-chen) guessed it).

Here are the offending lines reported by the compiler:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk/usr/include/complex.h:42:11: note: expanded from macro 'I'
#define I _Complex_I
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem using openSSL in a swift project to verify an in-app purchase receipt. I need to include x509.h which leads to the error above. I'm kinda new to the whole iOS development and I'm not sure whats the correct way to solve this issue? Is it OK to rename the I into i in rsa.h?

Comment: Yes, this should be enough to fix the build issue.